# How to make a mask for voronoi texture (with randomness)?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

[image]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

I created mask from gradient texture with *rgb mix node* but it cuts some voronoi cells in half.

edit: i need the voronoi position to act as a mask..so it didn't cut the voronoi cells.

any other solution is also great if it didn't cut the cells.

my english is bit rough..feel free to edit it

Comment: I've got something working, to some degree, but it's _very_ convoluted .. I'm afraid with the time I've got atm, this may wind up being too late for you.

Comment: I need to know the answer..anytime you can do it ..its good for me

Comment: I'm stuck, with avoiding overlaps. I'm detecting already occupied cells in a multi-layer Voronoi, but only by feeding back the modified UVs of all previous layers, which, in nodes,  is a kind of ridiculous tangle. You could iterate in OSL, a sort of roll-your-own voronoi, but then, no GPU. From a _practical_  POV, you could dump a load of rigid-body balls into a dish and bake a map from that, but I guess you want a procedural shader.

Comment: Hmm..if you find some solution in the future ..plz post it here ..or post a link of the solution..thanks for your time

Comment: Adding to the best answer, suppose it's impossible to do it with randomness and avoid cutting the circles, unless we make the circles have a diameter smaller or equal to the closest points visible on the project. Have to fiddle with a Math Node set to Less Than/Greater Than, or a Color Ramp set to Constant, make the circles smaller untill there is no cutting, meanwhile decrease the randomness

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The new Voronoi texture conveniently gives you a 'Position' output, which gives you (in 2D ) the X and Y coordinate of the center of a shading-point's cell.

So, if you don't want to cut your circle-'pixels' in half, you can use the distance of the *whole cell* from the texture space's origin to create a mask of whole cells, rather than the texture space itself.

[image]

I've scaled the whole texture down, so the cell-resolution is high enough to capture some circular curvature.

Comment: No, it won't cut the cells, but the cells themselves will be irregular.. and _circles_ may sometimes overlap, depending on your 'Distance' setting.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very good at asking. :)

Comment: added in the question..i dont know if i can upload somewhere else